# How do I refresh API endpoint without restarting my Express.js project

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, express, discord.js

I am making an API for my Discord Bot which lets you get data about someones Level and XP. However, it succeeds. There is one major flaw about this and it is that in order for the data to update in the JSON Object properly. My Bot will have to be restarted.

Here is the code:

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const db = require("quick.db")
let index = 0;
app.get("/", (request, response) => {

  response.sendStatus(200);
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT);
setInterval(() => {
  http.get(`http://${process.env.PROJECT_DOMAIN}.glitch.me/`);
}, 20000);
require('./index.js')

let levelldb = db.all().filter(data => data.ID.startsWith(`Leveling`)).sort((a, b) => b.data - a.data);
    { levelldb.length = 10; }

var levelldbs = function () {
  app.get('/api/levelldb', async function (req, res) {
    res.send(levelldb)
  })
  console.log(`Refreshed`)
} 
levelldbs();
```

This is what it looks like when I try to visit website.com/api/levelldb - It is successful.
[image]
Note: Please Ignore the null, that entirely means that data is awaiting to be collected and will be displayed there eventually when someone earns xp and levels.

There is no error with the code, it works how it should. So I am wondering how do I get the data to update automatically without the project restarting. I've tried using setInterval and setTimeout methods and wasn't able to get that worked out.

Welp I know it is going to annoying for me to restart everytime to get the data to show but I just want to know if I can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a single query result to be returned by your `/api/leveldb` route so the result is always the same. Move your data fetching from your data store into to have dynamic fetching based on the request.

Also, your app.get('route_name_here') doesn't need to be wrapped into a function. That is the external access point to the data you want to return from your api.

```
app.get('/api/levelldb', async function (req, res) {
    let levelldb = db.all()
          .filter(data => data.ID.startsWith(`Leveling`))
          .sort((a, b) => b.data - a.data);
        { levelldb.length = 10; }

    res.send(levelldb)
}
```

Reading up on [Express Routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) might help out as well.

Comment: This seems to resolve my issue. Also I had to fix a syntax error on the last line (right curly brace) and now that should do the trick! Thank you.